# I applied validation to my code still I guess its not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have writtn the code for validation...but while executing the app the validations are not working .like when i clicked the button without entering the details it should show the validations...but instead it is directed on the next page.

this is my activity_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="142dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="439dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_username"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="383dp"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ENTER USERNAME"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="325dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="263dp"
        android:hint="ENTER PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/DeepPink"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="373dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="124dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="147dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:onClick="LOGIN"
                android:text="LOGIN "
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="118dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="118dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="SIGN IN NOW"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="522dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ticket" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtusername;
    EditText txtpassword;
    Button textView2;
    ToastManager toastManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        textView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        Button textView3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button textView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent u = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(u);
            }
        });

    }




    public void LOGIN(final View view) {
        textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

                ToastManager toastManager = new ToastManager(MainActivity.this);

                boolean isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty = !username.isEmpty()
                        || !password.isEmpty();

                if (isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty) {
                    if (username.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    if (password.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types to call the actions
one: is setOnClickListenr
two: (xml) onClick

you are using both in your code

but when you use them both, (setOnClickListenr) will be execute

so the solution is to remove (setOnClickListenr) or remove the (android:onClick="LOGIN")

**EDIT:-** if you choice to take (setOnClickListenr) don't forget to copy the validation code and paste it in there body like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txtusername;
EditText txtpassword;
Button textView2;
ToastManager toastManager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
    txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    textView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    Button textView3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

            ToastManager toastManager = new ToastManager(MainActivity.this);

            boolean isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty = !username.isEmpty()
                    || !password.isEmpty();

            if (isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty) {
                if (username.isEmpty()) {
                    toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                    toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                    toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            } else {
                toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

have a nice day

Comment: Exactly what are u trying to say..can u be nore clear ..i am confused and I ma new to android studio so

Comment: okay, to do actions in android You have two ways
first one is via xml which is (android:onClick="LOGIN")
and the second one is via code which is (setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())

Comment: Okay So i removed (android:onClick="LOGIN") from my xml

Comment: you can't use them both, so just remove one of them from your code

Comment: Okay So i removed (android:onClick="LOGIN") from my xml

Comment: exactly, remove (android:onClick="LOGIN") from your xml, and take the code from (void LOGIN(final View view)) function and put it inside (textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) IN ONCREATE FUNCTION

Comment: Okay so I copy pasted that code ....but validations are not working ...........even my page is not getting intended

Comment: do you have anydesk?

Comment: applications to share screen (anydesk, teamViewer)

Comment: Should i download one??now??

Comment: yes, I'm planning to get in your device and fix the code for you

Comment: SO ShOULD I DOWNLOAD TEAMVIEWER OR ANYDESK

Comment: I prefer anydesk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225662/discussion-between-sank-and-mohammad-khair-pk).